# Is there a BASIC command to count the number of characters in a string?

Tags: basic, qbasic

I couldn't find any. Is there one? Google didn't help me, because it's case insensitive and thinks I am looking for "basic" commands.

Comment: What dialect of basic are you using?

Comment: Use LEN(variable$)

Answer (score 12):

Use LEN(*expression*), where the expression can be any string or string variable

Example:

```
X = LEN("Jack Daniels") >>> X contains 12
```

or

```
strX = "Jack"
X = LEN(strX) >>> X contains 4
```

Answer (score 7):

All Basic dialects I know of have a `len` function that returns the length of a string expression. Examples:

- [Apple // Integer basic](http://www.landsnail.com/a2ref2.htm)
- [Visual Basic 6](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions)
- [Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsw58z6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- http://www.fact-index.com/b/ba/basic_programming_language.html

In Visual Basic .NET you could also use the `.Length` property of the string, but that property behaves differently for the `Nothing` value: [Len() function vs String.Length property; which to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032312/len-function-vs-string-length-property-which-to-choose)

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Len**

```
Dim YourString as String

Dim CharCount as Integer

YourString ="MyString"

CharCount  = LEN(YourString)

msgbox "There are " & CharCount & " Characters in mystring"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to count the number of a specific character in a , you can do something like that :

```
Dim YourString as String

Dim CharCount as Integer


Dim MyChr as Char
Dim chrl as Char

YourString ="MyString"
MyChr ="A"


CharCount  = 0

For i = 1 To Len(YourString)


chrl = Mid(YourString, i, 1)
if UCase(chrl) = UCase(MyChr) then
CharCount  = CharCount  + 1
end if

next i


msgbox "There are " & CharCount & " " & MyChr & " Characters in mystring"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at this example:

```
' Initializes variable. 
Dim TestString As String = "Hello World" 
' Returns 11. 
Dim TestLen As Integer = Len(TestString)
```

So TestString = Hello World, and the TestLen = 11 because Hello World has 11 characters in it.

Answer (score -1):

```
conta = strlen(name_of_variable)
```

`strlen` gives the number of character of variables given an integer