# c# is there a easy way to convert month integer to name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, monthcalendar

I am trying to create a archive list for a blog application. I have a veiw model which has this code snippet:

```
@model IEnumerable<NPLHBlog.Models.ArchiveListModels>
...
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>@item.ArchiveMonth/@item.ArchiveYear : @item.PostCount</li>
        }
...
```

I am trying to print the item.ArchiveMonth as 'Jan' instead of '1'.

the ArchiveListModel is as follows:

```
public class ArchiveListModels
{
    public int ArchiveYear { get; set; }
    public int ArchiveMonth { get; set; }
    public int PostCount { get; set; }
}
```

and blogs are read from repository as follows:

```
    public IQueryable<ArchiveListModels> ArchiveList()
    {
        var archiveList = from blogs in db.Blogs
                          group blogs by new { blogs.PublishDate.Year, blogs.PublishDate.Month }
                              into dateGroup
                              select new ArchiveListModels()
                              {
                                  ArchiveYear = dateGroup.Key.Year,
                                  ArchiveMonth = dateGroup.Key.Month,
                                  PostCount = dateGroup.Count()
                              };
        return archiveList;
    }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a predefined enumeration for Month in the .NET library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899565/is-there-a-predefined-enumeration-for-month-in-the-net-library)

Comment: Not a duplicate question, but I think the answer will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the full month name

```
int month = 1;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month);
```

Or you can use the datetime string format:

```
int month = 1;
var dt = new DateTime(2012, month, 1):
var monthAbbr = dt.ToString("MMM");
```

Or you can do a lookup against the abbreviations list

```
int month = 1;
var monthAbbr =     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[month];
```

Comment: I had to use [month-1] for the 3rd option to give me correct abbreviated month.

Answer (score 11):

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1);
```

or for abrev

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[1];
```

Comment: I don't think this returns the abbreviated name, but nice to know.

Comment: for take abbreviated name use 3 symbols

Comment: Thanks for some reason CultureInfo was not working before. I had researched that on stackoverflow. Anyhow it works now!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want:

```
.ToString("MMM");
```

You can even create your own DateTime object for a specific month:

```
DateTime jan = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
return jan.Date.ToString("MMM");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ViewBags for the datas from your database you can also use that format easly. Just keep in mind.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.HealthCare)
{
    @item.Created_Date.ToString("MMMM yyyy")

}
```