# Why will the function PrintMaanden() print only the month itself, rather than the string I gave to each month?

Tags: c#, computer-science

I want the function **PrintMaanden()** to print every month with its string, e.g. *"1 => January"*
Instead the function prints just the month itself, e.g. *"January"*.

What did I do wrong here? Note that for this code I have to use the other function (that does work correctly as it is) **PrintMaand()** in the function **PrintMaanden()**.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program kalenderMaand = new Program();
    kalenderMaand.Start();
}

void Start()
{
    //New object month of type Month (class Month)
    Maanden maand;
    maand = new Maanden();
    PrintMaanden();
    PrintMaand(maand);

    //Read number of the month
    Console.Write("Typ het nummer van de maand: ");
    string month = Console.ReadLine();
    Maanden monthNumber = (Maanden)int.Parse(month);

    //Display the month based on the number that was typed
    switch (monthNumber)
    {
        case Maanden.Januari:
            Console.WriteLine("1 => Januari");
            break;
        case Maanden.Februari:
            Console.WriteLine("2 => Februari");
            break;
        case Maanden.Maart:
            Console.WriteLine("3 => Maart");
            break;
        case Maanden.April:
            Console.WriteLine("4 => April");
            break;
        case Maanden.Mei:
            Console.WriteLine("5 => Mei");
            break;
        case Maanden.Juni:
            Console.WriteLine("6 => Juni");
            break;
        case Maanden.Juli:
            Console.WriteLine("7 => Juli");
            break;
        case Maanden.Augustus:
            Console.WriteLine("8 => Augustus");
            break;
        case Maanden.September:
            Console.WriteLine("9 => September");
            break;
        case Maanden.Oktober:
            Console.WriteLine("10 => Oktober");
            break;
        case Maanden.November:
            Console.WriteLine("11 => November");
            break;
        case Maanden.December:
            Console.WriteLine("12 => December");
            break;
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}


void PrintMaand(Maanden maand)
{
    Console.WriteLine(maand);
}

void PrintMaanden()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        PrintMaand((Maanden) i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one other class called Maanden.cs , which is an enum file. It simply contains this:     public enum Maanden
    {
        Januari = 1, Februari, Maart, April, Mei, Juni, Juli, Augustus, September, Oktober, November, December
    }
}

Comment: Maybe this is what your looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/899589/758848

Comment: No. It isn't. I just need to know why it prints the month itself rather than the string I've defined in the switch.

Comment: Because your switch is not beeing called at PrintMaanden but after. The method PrintMaanden is just printing the WriteLine(maand).

Comment: I think you should move the whole switch case to the function PrintMaand(), and call PrintMaand() from start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
void PrintMaand(Maanden maand)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int) maand + " => " + maand);
}

void PrintMaanden()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        PrintMaand((Maanden) i);
    }
}
```

It's just of matter of formatting the result.

Answer (score 1):

The logic to pring both the month index/number as well as the name is not in the  PrintMaanden function. It is in the Start function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that what youre looking for:

```
void PrintMaand(Maanden maand)
{
    Console.Write(maand + "\n");
}

void PrintMaanden()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{i} => ");
        PrintMaand((Maanden) i);

    }
}
```

I used `Write` instead of `WriteLine` because this way you can write on the same line using your `PrintMaand()` method. And inside the PrintMaand() you have the `\n` for next line. The PrintMaanden formats the extra info you need for your new print.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void Start()
    {
        //New object month of type Month (class Month)
        Maanden maand;
        maand = new Maanden();

        //Calling the methods
        PrintMaanden();
        VraagMaand("Typ het nummer van de maand: ");


        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    void PrintMaand(Maanden maand)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(maand);
    }

    void PrintMaanden()
    {
        int teller = 0;
        for (Maanden i = Maanden.Januari; i <= Maanden.December; i++)
        {
            teller = teller + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,2}. {1}", teller, i));
        }
    }

    Maanden VraagMaand(string question)
    {
        //Read number of the month
        Console.Write(question);
        string month = Console.ReadLine();
        Maanden monthNumber = (Maanden)int.Parse(month);

        Console.Write("{0} => ", month);
        PrintMaand(monthNumber);
        return monthNumber;
    }
}
```

}

I figured it out, this was what I was looking for.