# PV Function and Porting VB6 to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm working on porting some classic VB6 code to C# and just stumbled across a usage of the `PV` function.

I feels wrong including a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic Assembly. Is this something that is commonly done, or should I explore further options. The next idea that pops into my mind is exploring this PV function in Reflector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The use of **Microsoft.VisualBasic** from C# and VB.NET has been discussed thoroughly under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226517/is-the-microsoft-visualbasic-namespace-true-net-code). The Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace is [fully supported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470), and will be around as long as .Net is around. There's no reason to avoid it.

**EDIT:** It's telling that at the time of typing, the other answers for this question are an *incorrect* reimplementation of the function, and a one-man-band unsupported library from Code Galleries. Come on guys, it would take a real [major event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolution) for Microsoft to drop the financial functions from VB.

It's a different story for **Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility**, which is exclusively for use by the VB6 upgrade wizard, **EDIT** *has now been marked obsolete in .Net 4* (my prediction came true), and should not be used for new development. There would be some advantages in removing references to this, but personally I'd probably try to achieve a fully working port first referencing.Net 3.5.

Comment: Agree 100% with this. Where does this reluctance to use Microsoft's supported library come from? Is it just the "ewwww... it says VB" mentality? WTF? Microsoft wrote VB6, C#, and then provided (for free) the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace for JUST THIS PURPOSE. And still people hesitate to use it. Whatever--Take your chances with some other "non-VB, therefore better" option.

Comment: Just to add: At the end of the day, it's all IL. I can write stuff in C#, Visual Basic.NET, IronPython and Boo and throw it all into the Blender (=compilers) and retrieve IL that doesn't know what it was before.

Comment: There is a stigma against using VB amongst C# developers and so because this have VisualBasic in the name they don't like it because they think they are programming in VB. Maybe MS should rename this to `Microsoft.ReallyUsefulAndFullySupportedFunctions` and everyone will be happy

Answer (score 3):

Pretty straight forward to replicate in C#

```
    public static double PV(double Rate, int nPer, double Pmt, double FV, bool Type)
    {
        double ann = Math.Pow(1 + Rate, nPer);
        return -(FV + Pmt * (1 + (Type ? Rate : 0)) * ((ann - 1) / Rate)) / ann;
    }
```

Just a re-arrangement of the formula Microsoft [provides](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052092251033.aspx).

Comment: It's almost a rearrangement of Microsoft's formula, except when rate=0. That's when your version divides by zero, and VB6 and Microsoft.VisualBasic return `-fv -(pmt*nper)`. There are pitfalls even in coding up a formula from a webpage. This reinforces my answer - for pity's sake just **use Microsoft.VisualBasic** and move on to implement something other functionality for the poor old users.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this library that duplicates excel functions in f#

[Library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/FinancialFunctions)

It has PV which is present value.  I have used it once or twice.  Just drop it in and add the reference.

Comment: hmmm seems kind of risky relying on a CTP language but I think I'd rather do that than reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic library

Comment: Exactly, when I've used it, it was to avoid excel automation and referencing Excel

Comment: The "NotStandAlone" version is almost 1 meg... almost tempted to just snag the PV function from Reflector, but I'll give this a shot

Comment: I prefer JDunkerley's solution - I'd rather add a 2 line function to my code rather than reference a whole assembly.

Comment: @Dave - -2 ( -1 because I don't agree, and another -1 because I'm a clueless SO noob and accidentally upvoted your comment, and can't undo it.  Doh! ;-) Seriously, there's some good stuff in the VB libraries (Shapes, for example). I think it's short sighted to not take advantage because of anti-VB snobbery.

Comment: @Tom Bushell I agree in this case if the function is accurate however the library also offers other functions like YTM which is much more difficult to replicate and was what I needed at the time.

Comment: @Tom you've twisted my arm, I'll just use it.

Comment: So you suggest using a one-man-band unsupported library from Code Galleries, just to avoid using a fully supported core library from the .NET framework? And this has received upvotes? Stack Overflow has blown a fuse. (Using it to get YTM might make sense but that wasn't the question in this case.)

Comment: @MarkJ I'm not suggesting he doesn't use Microsoft.VisualBasic  I simply pointed him to an alternative.  Unless I'm mistaken I believe that was what he was asking for.  I was pointed to that library myself from a similar question I posted.

Comment: Question was " Is this [avoiding Microsoft.VisualBasic] something that is commonly done, or should I explore further options". So if you point him to another library, you're implicitly advising removing Microsoft.VisualBasic. Or that's how I read it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the accepted answer, but I couldn't get it to work in .NET Core.  I did some looking around and ran across this code on github that appears to be Microsoft's implementation of PV:

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/Microsoft.VisualBasic/runtime/msvbalib/Financial.vb#L662

```
    Public Function PV(ByVal Rate As Double, ByVal NPer As Double, ByVal Pmt As Double, Optional ByVal FV As Double = 0, Optional ByVal Due As DueDate = DueDate.EndOfPeriod) As Double

        Dim dTemp As Double
        Dim dTemp2 As Double
        Dim dTemp3 As Double

        If Rate = 0.0# Then
            Return (-FV - Pmt * NPer)
        Else
            If Due <> 0 Then
                dTemp = 1.0# + Rate
            Else
                dTemp = 1.0#
            End If
            dTemp3 = 1.0# + Rate

            '       WARSI Using the exponent operator for pow(..) in C code of PV. Still got
            '       to make sure that they (pow and ^) are same for all conditions
            dTemp2 = dTemp3 ^ NPer

            'Do divides before multiplies to avoid OverFlowExceptions
            Return (-(FV + Pmt * dTemp * ((dTemp2 - 1.0#) / Rate)) / dTemp2)
        End If

    End Function
```

You'd still need to transpile it to C#.  If I have a general enough implementation at the end of this I'll post that too.