# Get Computer Name in C# without referencing Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way, other than referencing the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll (such as as below in .NET 3) to retrieve to Computer Name

```
new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer().Name
```

Comment: While the question is of course valid (and has an answer), I would just like to add that despite the DLL being called ".VisualBasic", it's all .net IL at the end, so there is no penalty in using it.

Comment: It's also a dupe...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768198

Comment: @Michael - I realised that, it just felt funny doing it, that's all :)

Comment: Apologies for the dupe, I did search. I think this is valid to stay open, as I was, as others have, searching for an alternative to the much used VisualBasic dll reference rather than just how do I get a computer name. A subtle distinction, but probably why I didn't find the answer given above, and others might find this one instead.

Comment: In this case it's unnecessary to use Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to find the computer name. But Michael makes a good point: there are useful functions in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, and you sometimes see people avoiding using it when it would really help them. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471918/pv-function-and-porting-vb6-to-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `System.Environment.MachineName`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use System.Windows.Forms.dll and the `SystemInformation` class. You can also use `System.Environment.MachineName` or `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME")`. And if you're really devoted, you can make a P/Invoke into user32.dll to call the appropriate Win32 API.