# Is there a VB 6 to VB.net conversion guide?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

While I used to VB 6 like the back of my hand, it has been a very long time I have never attempted to convert a large project. Are their any guides to help me along the process?

Comment: A quick search of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6+vb.net finds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030276/utility-to-convert-legacy-vb6-function-calls-to-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678064/vb6-to-vb-net-conversion, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241822/vb-runtime-functions-in-vb-net-for-vb6-programmers. Why didn't you?

Comment: BTW, voted to close as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395/how-to-switch-a-large-app-from-vb6-to-vb-net. Note that that's one of the first 1000 questions on SO.

Comment: @John Saunders: Good point; but then presumably the search mechanism during OP posting would have picked these up?

Comment: @Mitch: it picked up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678064/vb6-to-vb-net-conversion.

Comment: @John Saunders: I'm not looking for advice on converting single function calls, conversion tools, or VB runtime functions. I'm looking for the kind of stuff that Mitch Wheat provided.

Comment: @John Saunders: Your "exact duplicate" didn't actually answer my question, it just prattled on about how porting code should be avoided.

Comment: @Jonathan: it did answer the question - you just don't like that answer. Mitch's answer would have been a fine addition to that question.

Comment: @Jonathan I think you're criticising my answer to question 395? Let me respond. Question 395 is not an exact duplicate of your question here: 395 has several parts and I tried to answer all of them. I answered *does switching to .Net require a complete re-design and re-write?* with **NO there are other options** and gave some references. Then at the end of my answer, if you reached it, I gave some of the links I consider most helpful for migration. That part would be useful for you I think. I also suggest looking at the other questions tagged `vb6-migration`

Comment: @MarkJ: While your answer was far from useless, Mitch gave me the exact answer I was hoping for. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Dan Appleman's [Moving to VB .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059102X)

Also:

- [10 Things to Avoid When Moving From VB6 to VB.NET](http://vbnotebookfor.net/2007/08/07/10-things-to-avoid-when-moving-from-vb6-to-vbnet/)
- [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Migration Resource Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788233.aspx) (an excellent resource)
- [Moving from VB6 to VB.NET (Windows Forms)](http://dualbrain.com/blog/pages/Moving-from-VB6-to-VB.NET-_2800_Windows-Forms_2900_.aspx)

These 2 tools can be useful in conversions:

- [Code Advisor for Visual Basic 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a656371a-b5c0-4d40-b015-0caa02634fae&DisplayLang=en)
- [Visual Basic 6.0 to Visual Basic .NET Upgrade Assessment Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=10C491A2-FC67-4509-BC10-60C5C039A272&displaylang=en)

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: No problem. In all fairness, it is fairly similiar, and John did provide the SO links that I'd missed. I just wish SO had a better mechanism for grouping similiar questions...

Answer (score 1):

At this http://migrationguide.artinsoft.com/ you will find a good guide, as a matter of fact is a whole book addressing a lot of issues of VB6 migration.
You can also look at the blogs in artinsoft which provide good information and also there is a tool by this company that you can download from MSDN.