# Where should I initialize the user account of my WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, startup, user-accounts

I'm developing a WPF app used by multiple persons on a network.
On startup I want to get the user name from `Environment.UserName` and retrieve the user account from my database, then create a `User` object.

**Where should I do the user initialization?** It seems logical to add a member `User currentUser` to the `Application` and do the initialization in the `Main()` method, for example:

```
public class App : Application {
    public User CurrentUser {
        get; private set;
    }
    private Database database = new Database();

    public static void Main() {
        App app = new App();
        CurrentUser = database.getUser(Environment.UserName);
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

However **I'm having doubts since the `Main()` is auto generated in WPF.**

Comment: application has `Startup` event. add event handler and do initialization there

Comment: Who told you that Main is auto-generated? You can do whatever you want in your Main method

Comment: By default, `Main()` is auto generated and can be found in the `obj` folder (`obj\Debug\App.g.i.cs`). I know you can modify it manually but I don't know what the best practices in WPF are regarding `Main()` modifications.

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504939/how-to-stop-main-from-being-auto-generated-in-wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the `OnStartup` method in the `App` class in `App.xaml.cs`.

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about how you could implement custom authorization in WPF: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/