# What's the VB.NET method corresponding to the old CInt() VB method?

Tags: .net, vb.net, methods, double, type-conversion

I don't want use old Visual Basic methods in my code, and I'm confused about what's the newest VB.NET method corresponding to the old CInt() Visual Basic method.

For example,

```
Dim n1 as Double : n1 = CInt(2.1111111) 'Gets only 2 without rounding it
Dim n2 as Double : n2 = CInt(2.7777777) 'Get only 2 without rounding it
```

Comment: I don't want to round the value, but only truncate it by its decimal value as CInt() method.

Comment: CInt in VB6 performed rounding as well - see: http://www.chennaiiq.com/developers/reference/visual_basic/functions/cint.asp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [CInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in VB.NET as well. It is a standard [type conversion function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) supported by the VB.NET compiler. There is no reason to avoid it.

However, nearly every type conversion operation will *round* to the nearest integer (including other methods such as [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz), etc.), not truncate. You can force a truncation by using [Int or Fix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh29swte%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (which have different behaviors for negative numbers).

Note that, you can do the same as Int/Fix by using [Math.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx) and [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx), should you wish to avoid the VB.NET specific conversion routines.

---

On a side note - [CInt in Visual Basic 6.0](http://www.chennaiiq.com/developers/reference/visual_basic/functions/cint.asp) also performed rounding. The behavior in VB.NET for `CInt` is the same as in Visual Basic 6.0.

Comment: +1 Just use CInt. [There's no reason to avoid it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226517/is-the-microsoft-visualbasic-namespace-true-net-code). It is a [fully supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289509.aspx#vbtchmicrosoftvisualbasicnetinternalsanchor4) part of the .Net framework. Use CInt, move on, and get some actual work done.

Comment: @MarkJ I agree - if you're going to write in Visual Basic, you might as well *use* the tools provided by the language.  It's kind of like saying "I want to avoid using int in C#, and am going to always write `System.Int32` because that's how the framework defines it"...

Comment: Ah, your answer was better than mine anyway.  Yours usually are.  ;-)

Comment: You will also find that the CInt method is NOT in Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.  That is where all the old compatibility methods are at.

Comment: @RobertBeaubien No - CInt is directly provided by the language.

Comment: Like I said with that big "NOT" in my statement.  He was worried about using old stuff.

Comment: @RobertBeaubien - No.  The compatibility methods are in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility assembly.  Microsoft.VisualBasic contains namespaces such as CompilerServices, FileIO, and the My functionality and are not just for compatibility.