# Bug in Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.MoveFile() dialog?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I use the above mentioned method in my CSharp code as it is really convenient. But apparently there is a bug in the UI when a file is to be replaced.

```cs
var fileOri = @"D:\Temp\overwritetest_ori.txt";
var fileToOverwrite = @"D:\Temp\overwritetest\overwritetest.txt";
FileSystem.MoveFile(fileOri, fileToOverwrite, UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.DoNothing);
```

When the file `D:\Temp\overwritetest\overwritetest.txt` exists the dialog shows this:

[image: FileOverwriteDialog]

Now is this a bug or do I use the code not how it's supposed to be?

> The dialog says "The destination already has a file named "overwritetest_ori.txt"", which is not true. There is only a file "overwritetest.txt" which happens to be the target name of the move operation. So the dialog's text should be "The destination already has a file named "overwritetest.txt".

Comment: Could you explain what aspect you believe to be a bug? Bear in mind that questions are expected to be in English - if we need to understand German in order to understand the question (because it's something to do with the text of the dialog box) that's a problem. If you change your OS locale to English, you could capture the dialog in English, which would make for a better question - although it would still be worth explaining why you think there's a bug.

Comment: The dialog says "The destination already has a file named "overwritetest_ori.txt"", which is not true. There is only a file "overwritetest.txt" which happens to be the target name of the move operation. So the dialog's text should be "The destination already has a file named "overwritetest.txt"...

Comment: Just exchanged the dialog's language per Jon's explanation. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: That's much better, yes. Close vote retracted :) Will try to reproduce this myself...

Comment: I can repro - certainly seems like a bug in `FileSystem.MoveFile()`

Comment: ... it seems like a problem in the system in `SHFileOperation` method from `shell32.dll` ... I pretty sure that if you would feed this method with the same data and call it from C/C++/direct pinvoke you would get the same results

Comment: Agreed, the code goes all the way to `SHFileOperation` without too much logic involving file existence, and that box is a popup from the native code. I suggest you file a bug with Microsoft.

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.MoveFile` and other classes in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace exist only for compatibility with legacy VB6 applications (think pre-2000), not for convenience. They're usually thin wrappers over features that already exist in other .NET classes and may only require 1 or 2 extra lines.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: Yep, 20-24 years ago Windows 9x still run on FAT, and the shell operations used FAT semantics. Windows NT didn't even have those shell operations until NT 4.0. Windows Vista and later used *different* shell operations. `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem` was built for compatibility with the File Scirpting Object introduced with IE 4.0

Comment: this is prolly simple bug in resources (shell32.dll.mui) resource id 33234 there is `%1!s!` ... it prolly should be  `%2!s!` if both files names are passed for formatting or destenation file name should be passed in the code (if only one is passed for formatting)

Comment: What i imagine that this is 1. Rename file and then 2.Overwrite which can be the reason.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are probably thinking [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/226708/11683).

Comment: @HansPassant The 8.3 filenames do not seem relevant?

Comment: These files have the same 8.3 short name, typically overwr~1.txt.  The dialog message is not ideal, but I'd personally couldn't come up with a better one that my Mom would understand.

Comment: @HansPassant I know that the file names are not the best choice :-)
But actually even totally different source and destination names produce the same result - so, no, I don't think 8.3 comes into play here.

Comment: @HansPassant The message appears not because the 8.3 name may clash, but because the OP wants to move the file while renaming it, and the new name clashes with the existing one. They are genuinely the same irrespective to their 8.3 variants. The problem is that the dialog displays the wrong clashed file name, not that the dialog appears at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in [the Windows `SHFileOperation` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationw) rather than a bug in `FileSystem.MoveFile()`, as can be demonstrated by the code below.

If you run the code below with the files in place as per the OP's question, then you get the same message box:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Console1;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var fileOri         = @"D:\Temp\overwritetest_ori.txt";
        var fileToOverwrite = @"D:\Temp\overwritetest\overwritetest.txt";

        SHFileOperationApi.MoveFile(fileOri, fileToOverwrite);
    }
}

public static class SHFileOperationApi
{
    const int FO_MOVE = 0x1;
    const int FOF_ALLOWUNDO = 0x40;
    const int FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING = 0x4000;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public int wFunc;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pFrom;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pTo;
        public ushort fFlags;
        public bool fAnyOperationsAborted;
        public IntPtr hNameMappings;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string lpszProgressTitle;
    }

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int SHFileOperation(ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT lpFileOp);

    public static void MoveFile(string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        var fileOpStruct = new SHFILEOPSTRUCT {
            hwnd = IntPtr.Zero,
            wFunc = FO_MOVE,
            pFrom = sourceFile + "\0",
            pTo = destinationFile + "\0", // Double-null terminated
            fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING
        };

        SHFileOperation(ref fileOpStruct);
    }
}
```

Gives:

[image: The error message]

Comment: Prolly nobody test this out as you can't do this from the shell directly - from shell the source and destination file have the same name